Inverse of a circulant matrix via DFT
I am trying to do some practice in computing the inverse of a circulant matrix via the formula Inverse of a circulant matrix. I got that the first row of the inverse is
\begin{equation}\label{a}\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{F(0, 0)}{f_0\mathbf{x}}+\frac{F(1, 0)}{f_1\mathbf{x}}+\cdots +\frac{F(n-1, 0)}{f_{n-1}\mathbf{x}},\\ \frac{F(0, 1)}{f_0\mathbf{x}}+\frac{F(1, 1)}{f_1\mathbf{x}}+\cdots +\frac{F(n-1, 1)}{f_{n-1}\mathbf{x}},\\ \vdots \\ \frac{F(0, n-1)}{f_0\mathbf{x}}+\frac{F(1, n-1)}{f_1\mathbf{x}}+\cdots +\frac{F(n-1, n-1)}{f_{n-1}\mathbf{x}}\bigg),\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where $F$ denotes $\mathbf{F}_N$ (of the corresponding formula), its rows and columns are indexed by $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, and $f_i$ stands for the $i$-th row. I believe that this has further simplifications, but I do not see them. If I take $\mathbf{x}=(1, -1, 0, 0, -1)$, then the first row of the inverse is $(1, 0, -1, -1, 0)$, which can be computed from the previous expression after some time spent. Is there any hint on how to do this more elegantly and how to deal with general case? In particular, is there an upper bound for
$$\frac{1}{f_0\mathbf{x}}+\frac{1}{f_1\mathbf{x}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{f_{n-1}\mathbf{x}}~?$$
